# kotlin Firebase Variable path

Tags: arrays, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Quick question.
While I write away my data to my firebase database I'd like to order it.
since i'm making an Album collection list I'd love to have it like the picture underneath.. but with bands and albums tho.

[image]

the only problem is that I can't read my write string.. in this case $Uname
I can only read the data correctly if I hardcode the location in my .getReference()

my data upload code:

```
        //values

        val number = Number_tv.text.toString()
        val Uname = Username_TV.text.toString()
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/userdata/$Uname/$number _key")
        val user = User(Username_TV.text.toString(), Email_TV.text.toString(), albumimageURL)

        //code
        if (number.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Number is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        else{
        ref.setValue(user)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("mainacti", "upload succesful")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("mainacti", "I do not work")
            }}


    }
```

my data download code:

```
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/userdata/Heinz")
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
                p0.children.forEach {
                    Log.d("Albumlist", it.toString())
                    val user = it.getValue(User::class.java)
                    if (user != null){
                        adapter.add(UserItem(user))
                    }

                }
                recyclerview_album.adapter = adapter
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
    }
```

Both codes are in different classes

here's a Log for the reference ("/userdata")

```
2021-04-16 13:00:42.080 6914-6914/com.example.firetrier D/Albumlist: DataSnapshot { key = Hans, value = {1 _key={albumimageURL=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fireupload-4be26.appspot.com/o/albumcover%2Fcb06a4c4-8795-4103-99ef-c2bd55498b2e?alt=media&token=7d3d305e-c266-41fb-b466-cab548fbdd35, email=hans@test.com, username=Hans}} }
2021-04-16 13:00:42.088 6914-6914/com.example.firetrier D/Albumlist: DataSnapshot { key = Heinz, value = {1 _key={albumimageURL=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fireupload-4be26.appspot.com/o/albumcover%2Ff00f6651-9ccf-4533-8e1c-af103a1a17e6?alt=media&token=b6e4ad2f-cb4f-47d5-8f00-02bdc4765c00, email=Heinz@doof.com, username=Heinz}, 5 _key={albumimageURL=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fireupload-4be26.appspot.com/o/albumcover%2Fc9bb80aa-15a2-48cb-b6f5-6b7a59b11d8d?alt=media&token=facd516d-c3e3-4b61-aa09-23ea9062ccd3, email=hans@test.com, username=Heinz}} }
```

is there a way to use the value instead of the key?
if I adapt the reference to one of the usernames this is the log

```
2021-04-16 13:05:54.028 7629-7629/com.example.firetrier D/Albumlist: DataSnapshot { key = 1 _key, value = {albumimageURL=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fireupload-4be26.appspot.com/o/albumcover%2Ff00f6651-9ccf-4533-8e1c-af103a1a17e6?alt=media&token=b6e4ad2f-cb4f-47d5-8f00-02bdc4765c00, email=Heinz@doof.com, username=Heinz} }
2021-04-16 13:05:54.040 7629-7629/com.example.firetrier D/Albumlist: DataSnapshot { key = 5 _key, value = {albumimageURL=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fireupload-4be26.appspot.com/o/albumcover%2Fc9bb80aa-15a2-48cb-b6f5-6b7a59b11d8d?alt=media&token=facd516d-c3e3-4b61-aa09-23ea9062ccd3, email=hans@test.com, username=Heinz} }
```

Comment: If you log `Uname`, what is its value?

Comment: These are two different classes.. Should have mentioned that. The idea is that one class makes a new item and the other class shows it in a recyclerview.

Comment: Does your application use Firebase Authentication or is there any source of  getting name of current user?